# What is different create() and fetch()?

Tags: twilio

I want to make a python script about Twilio flow execution.
I read Twilio the documentation about execution, but I can't understand the difference between
 `create()` and `fetch()`.
 If I want to execute my Twilio studio flow, which should I use?
What is different?

Please help me.

```
execution = client.studio \
                  .flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                  .executions \
                  .create(to='+15558675310', from_='+15017122661')


execution = client.studio \
                  .flows('FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
                  .executions \
                  .create(parameters={
                       'foo': 'bar'
                   }, to='+15558675310', from_='+15017122661')
```

Comment: This is twilio document.https://jp.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution#fetch-a-single-execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [`fetch` an execution](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution?code-sample=code-fetch-execution&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) the result will be a representation of an execution that happened. You can look up details like what the contact channel address of the execution was, or the execution's current status.

When you [`create` an execution](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution?code-sample=code-fetch-execution&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) it triggers the flow to start using the parameters you include in the request. Using `create` will start a communication flow with a user.

Let me know if that helps at all.